# ImageButtons are not getting aligned

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to align three ImageButton  the attribute  `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`  is working but  `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` is not working, I am not able to find out the issue, Please anybody help me...Thanks in advance

activity_main.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_for_edittext" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_go"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/save_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_go"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_go"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enteraddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_address" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_96"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mapView_Button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_current_location" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_96"
    android:contentDescription="@string/refresh_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
    android:text="@string/refresh_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnListview"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/box_96"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mapView_Button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add

`android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"`

in the last `ImageButton`

your code. :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_for_edittext" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_go"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/save_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_go"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_go"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enteraddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_address" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_96"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mapView_Button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_current_location" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_96"
    android:contentDescription="@string/refresh_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
    android:text="@string/refresh_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnListview"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_96"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mapView_Button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying...eclipse doesn't show the applied or changed parameters in graphical layout, While I can see those changes on real device

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the `android:layout_marginBottom` arrtibut = 10 dp for all the 3 buttons like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
    ...other attributes...
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    ...other attributes... />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
    ...other attributes...
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    ...other attributes.../>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnListview"
    ...other attributes...
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    ...other attributes... />
```

You kept 10dp only for first button, 14dp for 2nd button, and didn't specify `layout_marginBottom` for 3rd button.
You should add 10dp for all 3 buttons